# Proving that a multivariable function is surjective?

Tags: linear-algebra

I more or less understand what I'm trying to do here, I'm just doubtful of my linear system manipulation; I feel like I'm going wrong somewhere. Can someone let me know if I'm doing something wrong?

We have $f$: $\mathbb R$$^3$ $\to$ $\mathbb R$$^3$ defined by

$f(x,y,z) = (x - y + 2z, -x +y -z, 2x - y + z)$

I want to show that $\forall$$y$ $\in$ $\mathbb R$$^3$, $\exists$$x$ $\in$ $\mathbb R$$^3$ such that $f(x) = y$

So,

take any $(x,y,z)$$\in$ $\mathbb R$$^3$, we have $(a,b,c)$$\in$ $\mathbb R$$^3$ such that $f(x,y,z) = (a,b,c)$

$\Rightarrow$ $(x - y + 2z, -x +y -z, 2x - y + z) = (a,b,c)$

$\Rightarrow$
1. $x - y + 2z = a \\
2. -x +y -z = b \\
3. 2x - y + z = c$

(do 1<-2, 3<-2)):

$\Rightarrow$ 
1) $z = a + b\\
2) -x +y -z = b \\
3) x = c + b$

(replace the values of x and z into 2):

$\Rightarrow$ 
1) $z = a + b\\
2) y = b + x + z = b + (c + b) + (a + b) = a+ 3b + c \\
3) x = c + b$

Thus, $\forall$ $(x,y,z)$, we have a $(a,b,c)$ for which $f(x,y,z) = (a,b,c)$

I'm almost 100% I've done something wrong, but I just don't know how to go about doing this the 'proper way'; what is there to fix?

Quick follow up question:
$\forall$ $(a,b,c)$$\in$$\mathbb R$$^3$, what are the conditions of $(a,b,c)$ such that $(a,b,c)$$\in$ f($\mathbb R$$^3$).

Wouldn't the conditions be the same as the ones found when looking for surjectivity?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Apologies for the poor formatting, I couldn't find a way of making nice long curly brackets. Thank you.

Comment: Write this in matrix form $f(x) = Ax$ and calculate $\det(A)$ or $A^{-1}$ to make your work more concise.

Comment: Any linear map on $\Bbb R^n$ which maps each $n$-tuple to a $n$-tuple formed by the linear combination of its arguments is a matrix transformation $X\mapsto AX$ where $A\in M_n(\Bbb R)$. In your example, we have $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&-1&2\\-1&1&-1\\2&-1&1\end{pmatrix}$. In general, this map is bijective iff $\det(A)\neq 0$

Comment: @PrasunBiswas Thanks for your response. I have a few follow up questions. What happens if its going from R2 to R3, would I still be able to use this method? Secondly, and this may be a stupid question, but why are we trying to show that the map is bijective, and not surjective. Thank you.

Comment: @user494405: If the map is $\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^3$, then the matrix $A$ wouldn't be a square matrix, so $\det(A)$ is not clearly defined, so the above isn't meaningful in that context. Regarding your second question, I wanted to inform that a stronger result holds (bijectivity implies surjectivity as well as injectivity).

Comment: @PrasunBiswas Oh of course, that makes sense. However, just because$\det(A)\neq 0$ implies bijectivity doesn't mean that if $\det(A) = 0$ we don't have surjectivity, no? So if $\det(A) =  0$, I'd have to do another test to check if it's surjective if I am convinced that it is? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is correct, you directly solved the system and prove that always we can obtain a solution for all $(a,b,c)\in\mathbb{R^3}$ and thus that $f$ is surjective.

As an alternative we can show that the system

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&2\\-1&1&-1\\2&-1&1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}$$

has always solution, that is matrix $A$ is not singular, indeed $\det(A)=-1\neq 0$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have a few follow up questions, if you don't mind. Firstly, how would I do this without using matrices? I ask this because we did these kinds of problems way before we were taught about matrices. With my less efficient method, where am I going wrong? Thank you.

Comment: @user494405 Your way is also good, you directly solved the system and prove that always you obtain a solution, thif that f is surjective. I didn't check the details of the derivation but the method is fine without matrices.

Comment: Oh, alright, thanks. So I assume this is the preferred way? All I have to do is to prove that the matrix isn't 0? What if the map is different, say, from R^2 to R^3, would it work the same way? Also, I think the way I manipulated the linear system above was wrong, would you mind telling me why? Thanks again.

Comment: @user494405 The way is correct and also the result, I've checked it and the solution works.

Comment: @user494405 a map from $R^2$ to $R^3$ can't never be surjective

Comment: @user494405 You can also check directly bu your self, it is easy for example for the first equation we obtain $$x-y+2z=c+b-a-3b-c+2a+2b=a$$

Comment: Ah of course, that makes sense. I could also simply plug in the values into f and it should return a,b,c, right?

Comment: @user494405 Yes, make this kind of check is very important when it is possible! In this case it is simple and effective.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help (and your patience), I really appreciate it. (I just rememered that they advice people not to comment just to thank someone; then again, it would feel rude not to, so whatever.)

Comment: @user494405 You are welcome! Your work was very good! Bye

Answer (score 1):

Your function is $$ f \begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&2\\-1&1&-1\\2&-1&1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{pmatrix}$$

Therefore, $$ \begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=    \begin{bmatrix}1&-1&2\\-1&1&-1\\2&-1&1     \end{bmatrix}^{-1} \begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{pmatrix}$$

Note that the inverse exists because the determinant of your matrix is $-1$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have a follow up question: If I find that the determinant is non-zero, then does that mean that the whole function is bijective? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it does. $Ax=Ay \implies x=y$ because  $A^{-1}$ exists.