# Showing inclusion of multivariable function

Tags: linear-algebra

Ok, I know that the title doesn't make much sense, but I didn't know how to describe this question, and I didn't want to simply put "linear algebra question". Anyway:

We have $f: \mathbb R^3 → \mathbb R^3$ defined by

$f(x,y,z)=(x−y+2z,−x+y−z,2x−y+z)$

If I have $(a,b,c)\in \mathbb R^3$, under what conditions do we have that $(a,b,c)\in f(\mathbb R^3)$.

I'm not really sure how to go about this problem. Would the conditions be the same as the conditions I found when proving that this function is surjective? ([Proving that a multivariable function is surjective?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2725537/proving-that-a-multivariable-function-is-surjective/2725617#2725617)) My intuition tells me that the conditions are the same, but I'm still not sure as to how this is supposed to be answered formally. Any guidance is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: **HINT**: Have you learned about the column space of a matrix?

Comment: @TedShifrin This was a question from the beginning of my semester. Since then, I have learned about the column space, but only on a basic level. However, at the time, we were meant to solve the problem with more basic maths, I believe. I would of course like to know how to solve this question with both ways, though.

Comment: I think the point of the problem is to make you appreciate the techniques you're going to learn in the linear algebra class. Otherwise, you're just going to slog through a system of linear equations by brute force.

Comment: @TedShifrin I think you're right. With that said, I still don't feel like I'm comfortable enough with linear systems, and would like to work on it.

Comment: Set up the augmented matrix with $a,b,c$ as the final column and go for it.

Comment: @TedShifrin But the thing is, I feel like this question was already answered when I proved surjectivity. Would you mind checking the link I posted and tell me if those conditions are the same as the conditions I'm looking for?

Comment: Well, of course, if the mapping is surjective, the question is quite easy. But, if it's not, characterizing the image of the function is precisely characterizing the column space of the matrix, and you should have learned algorithms for this once you find an echelon form of the matrix.